# Mongoose Schema in NodeJS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Item is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

I'm building a cafe website with NodeJS, Express, and Mongo. I'm attempting to create a new cafe in one of my routes with a get request using a model I created. However, I keep getting an TypeError in my terminal stating that Cafe is not a constructor. I don't understand because I have defined the Schema in a separate file and I've included it in my app.js (routes file). Any feedback about this error is appreciated. I've included a few photos along with the code. Thank you in advance!

```
 const path = require('path')
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const Cafe = require("./models/cafe");

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cafe-hopping', {
   useNewURLParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
 })

 const db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
 db.once("open", () => {
   console.log("Database connected");
 });

 const app = express() 

 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

 app.get('/createcafe', async(req, res) => {
   const cafes = new Cafe ({ name: 'Cueva Matera', description: "A cave like theme cafe"});
   await cafes.save();
   res.send(cafes)
}) 

*The following is the Schema (the file name is cafe.js)*

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CafeSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   price: String,
   description: String,
   location: String
});

module.export = mongoose.model('Cafe', CafeSchema);

[![app.js file. This is where I am keeping all of my routes][1]][1]
[![cafe.js file. This is where I create a new Schema for the database][2]][2]
[![This is the server error message I'm getting in my terminal every time I send the /createcafe get request][3]][3]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgTYg.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Ibx.png
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFzzJ.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you should be using

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cafe', CafeSchema);
```

Instead of `module.export`

Because of the misnamed property (`export` vs `exports`) the schema is not getting exported correctly, and `Cafe` is not a constructor.

Comment: @Liz7 I'd appreciate if you could accept the answer if it solved the problem. That would help indicate to others that have a similar issue that this was the resolution.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will do this!